# Warp text on a row with an input

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a situation where I need to wrap text with an input in Flutter. An example: 'The cat goes `<TextField>`, the dog goes bark.'

I'm using the Row class to format it this way, however, the row class doesn't wrap text.

```
Widget _buildQuestionText(String sentence) {
 List splitSentence = sentence.split('\$guess');

  return new Container(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(splitSentence[0]),
        new Expanded(child: new TextField()),
        new Text(splitSentence[1]),
      ]
    ),
  );
}
```

Which creates:

[image: Text does not wrap]

I have looked at using the Flex class but was unable to achieve the format I wanted. How can I achieve text wrapping with an input in the middle of text?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to make multiple bits of text that each wrap, or do you want an entire sentence with an input in the middle of it with the entire thing wrapping?

Comment: Sentence with an input in the middle of it with the entire thing wrapping. Thanks!

Comment: looks like you need a *Wrap* and not a *Row*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap accepts a list of children that wraps while row accepts a list of children that do not wrap.

```
return new Container(
      child: new Wrap(
        spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
        runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
        children: [
          new Text(splitSentence[0]),
          new Container(              
            width: 100.0,
            child: new TextField(                                 
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.black                  
              )
            )
          ),
          new Text(splitSentence[1]),
        ],
      )
    );
```